# Having problem converting object to float pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have been trying to "format" one column from object to float. I have tried quite few solutions posted here, but none of them have given me the results I need (and want).
I have checked the csv file, and the numbers in that column are formatted as numbers.

So here goes. I have some empty lines (which is ok). This is how the data looks like when I import it
[image]

Now third column (Vísitala neysluverðs Grunnur frá 1981) is an object here.

I have tried to do

```
In[1]
cpi['Vísitala neysluverðs Grunnur frá 1981'] = cpi['Vísitala neysluverðs Grunnur frá 1981'].astype(float)

Out[1]
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '100,00'

In[2]
cpi['Vísitala neysluverðs Grunnur frá 1981'] = cpi['Vísitala neysluverðs Grunnur frá 1981'].astype(str).astype(float)

Out[2]
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '100,00'

In[3]
cpi['Vísitala neysluverðs Grunnur frá 1981'] = cpi['Vísitala neysluverðs Grunnur frá 1981'].str().astype('float64')

Out[3]
TypeError: 'StringMethods' object is not callable
```

The only method which has not given me an error is

```
cpi['Vísitala neysluverðs Grunnur frá 1981'] = pd.to_numeric(cpi['Vísitala neysluverðs Grunnur frá 1981'], errors='coerce')
```

BUT, that turns all of the float values into NaN like so

[image]

That reduces the amount of data I have to work with significantly.
I know this is not this difficult, I just haven't found the correct way to keep all of the floats there.

Regards
Ólafur

Comment: did you mean to add a link in your second opening sentence, it can be added with the following syntax: [here](link)

Comment: No, I was not going to add a link :) Thank you for the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue might be originating from the comma in each number. Before converting to float try using the `replace` function. This will replace the comma with nothing, leaving a string that can be converted into a float.

```
number.replace(',', '')
```

Comment: Will give that a go,,, I think I tried that as well, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: Well, haven''t managed to get `replace` to work on my data, I did `cpi['Vísitala neysluverðs Grunnur frá 1981'].replace(',', '')
` and  `cpi.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',', ''))`. But there is no difference in my data.

Comment: This one did the trick `cpi['Vísitala neysluverðs Grunnur frá 1981'] = cpi['Vísitala neysluverðs Grunnur frá 1981'].str.replace(',', '').astype(float)
`

Comment: The problem with this is that I lose my decimal point, which I also need. If I am able to get that into the data, I am in business.

Comment: Is the comma meant to represent a decimal point in this data? If so that should be a simple fix, just use replace(',', '.') instead of replace(',', ' ')

Comment: I did try that, but that gave an error, because somewhere in the data the comma is a thousand separator and decimal separator. I will just divide by 1000 to get the decimal separator instead.